# Unable to make pdf no error in console!

Tags: errors, output

Suddenly today I couldn't create a file I had been working on earlier, and then it was working just fine. Then when I restarted the program I got the error "Underfull \hbox badness 10000 \textbf" and googled it and then removed all my '\' (never had a problem with it before). Now I copied the first template lines from another document but still can't produce a pdf!

I get this console:
[image: What is this?]

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{article}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{setspace}
\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage[swedish]{babel}
\usepackage{float}
\title{Algebra III\\ \textit{Assignment 2}}
\author{me}
\begin{document}
\maketitle
\newpage
```

Comment: you need an `\end{document}`

Comment: Well that was easy.... must have deleted it by mistake! Thank you!!

Comment: mistakes happen :) in the future, please post your minimal examples directly as code, as I've done in the edit.

Comment: I'll make sure to do that!

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look at [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is caused by a simple error in the user input.

Answer (score 1):

Without `\end{document}`, TeX will never finalize the output -- no PDF file will be produced.